# How can I prevent multiple instance processes from being created in a single Android application?

Tags: android, process, share

While developing my Android application, I have implemented a feature that handles shared YouTube links using the "Share" functionality. The link is passed for processing, but when the application is running in the background and I tap on the share option, it launches a new instance of the application instead of performing the task in the original instance. I have tried adding `android:launchMode="singleTask"` to my Manifest, but it didn't work.

What can I do to make it perform the task in the existing instance?

Comment: "it launches a new instance of the application instead of performing the task in the original instance" -- please explain **in detail** how you have determined this, and how you have determined that whatever you are seeing reflects "multiple instance processes".